# Powershell to open and edit HTML file

Tags: html, powershell, editing

I was wondering if anyone could please help me with below issue.

I have the below HTML file and what i would like to do is use Powershell to edit some of the rows.

```
<br>
<H3><U><FONT COLOR=blue>Server1</U></font></H3>
<table border="1" BORDERCOLOR=black>
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tr><th>Drive</th><th>SizeGB</th><th>UsedGB</th><th>FreeGB</th><th>Usage</th></tr>
<tr><td>C:</td><td>68</td><td>36.73</td><td>30.88</td><td><Font color=Red>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</Font><Font Color=Green>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>D:</td><td>837</td><td>250.13</td><td>586.49</td><td><Font color=Red>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</Font><Font Color=Green>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>E:</td><td>1023</td><td>193.35</td><td>829.65</td><td><Font color=Red>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</Font><Font Color=Green>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</font></td></tr>
</table>

<br>
<H3><U><FONT COLOR=blue>File Server</U></font></H3>
<table border="1" BORDERCOLOR=black>
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tr><th>Drive</th><th>SizeGB</th><th>UsedGB</th><th>FreeGB</th><th>Usage</th></tr>
<tr><td>C:</td><td>68</td><td>24.28</td><td>43.43</td><td><Font color=Red>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</Font><Font Color=Green>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>D:</td><td>706</td><td>601.68</td><td>104.63</td><td><Font color=Red>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</Font><Font Color=Green>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>E:</td><td>409</td><td>248.92</td><td>160.26</td><td><Font color=Red>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</Font><Font Color=Green>¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦</font></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
```

So what i need is to go though the HTML file and only edit section past File Server, set D: to "Files" and set E: to "Data", save and close with the default name.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the string as you posted it in a variable called $test:

```
$new = $test -replace '(^.+File Server.+)D:(.+)E:(.+$)', '$1Files$2Data$3'
```

Then just save $new out to the file.